# How to Save In App Purchase state in Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, keychain

Inside my app the user can purchase a `non-consumable product`. My problem right now is that I don't quite know how to store the information correctly wether or not a user has bought the product or not. I read the `User Defaults` is not the most secure way, so I tried it with `Keychain`. For that I am using [this](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) helper lib.

Now this is how I tried implementing it:

```
keychain["isPremium"] = "true"             // set the state
let token = try? keychain.get("isPremium") // get the state to check if it worked
print(token as Any)
```

This is printing "true". However if I logout the user, and login with another account and I only call this:

```
let token = try? keychain.get("isPremium")
```

it still prints out "true" even though the second user hasn't purchased the item. How can I store the state of the IAP in my app then ?

Comment: There is no such a thing as THE right way.  If you are talking about how to use the code you are referring to, talk to the guy who wrote it.  Nobody here is responsible for it.

Comment: @ElTomato  got you, guess I asked my question wrong. I want to save the state in `Keychain`. But I can not make it work. I thought that the problem I have is more like a general problem and not specific to the repo, plus the repo is quite popular so maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Click on Issues at GitHub and see if there are any issues, you can post your issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entirely depends on your application logic, the Keychain is working as expected: you save something to it, then read it out again (unchanged). The Keychain has no way of knowing what other kinds of logic is taking place in your app.

That said, you could do something simple like just storing each user's unlock state with a different key in the Keychain, based off some kind of user identifier.

```swift
// holds the current logged in user ID
// this needs to be persisted across the user's session,
// so store this somewhere like UserDefaults or the Keychain 
// (depending on your app's security model)
//
// I just use a simple variable for this example
var currentUserID = ""

// user 1 logs in, set:
currentUserID = "user1_"

keychain[currentUserID + "isPremium"] = "true"   
let token = try? keychain.get(currentUserID + "isPremium")
print(token as Any) 

// user 2 logs in, set:
currentUserID = "user2_"

keychain[currentUserID + "isPremium"] = "true"
let token = try? keychain.get(currentUserID + "isPremium")
print(token as Any)
```

Comment: looks promising! I will give it a try